# Optimisation Issue Python

Tags: python, class, object, optimization, numba

I'm trying to optimize a method for my library that I use for my discord bot
but I have no idea how can i optimize this method.
It's a method that is mainly doing strings operations to render a string
that has 2 dimensions like in old games that were only made of characters.

I was thinking to use things like Numba and Numpy
but it doesn't seem to support this method.
So what should I do in my case ?

Here is The Code I've writen :

```py
def render(self, is_string=True):
        """
        Returns the rendered canvas as a string if "is_string" is true else as a 2D-list
        """

        line = self.canvas_owner.void * self.size["x"] + "\n"
        rows = list(self.row_render_dict.keys())
        rows.sort()

        canvas = ""

        number_of_row_to_render = len(self.row_render_dict)
        last_row = 0

        if len(rows) == 0:
            # nothing to render
            canvas = line * self.size["y"]
            return canvas
        else:
            last_row = rows[0]

        canvas += line * (rows[0])  # adds line before the first one

        for todo_row in rows:

            number_to_fill_up = todo_row - 1 - last_row

            if number_to_fill_up > 0:
                canvas += line * number_to_fill_up
            
            last_row = todo_row

            x_to_render_line = list(self.row_render_dict[todo_row].keys())
            x_to_render_line.sort()
            render_line = ""
            sprites_to_render = len(x_to_render_line)
            items_rendered = 0  # also includes void

            # todo_line is the character position that gets rendered

            for todo_line in x_to_render_line:

                # fill up with "void" until something to render
                number_to_fill_up = (todo_line - items_rendered)
                if number_to_fill_up > 0:
                    # if there is something that can be filled up
                    render_line += self.canvas_owner.void * number_to_fill_up
                    items_rendered += number_to_fill_up

                

                row_dict = self.row_render_dict[todo_row]
                render_line += row_dict[todo_line][0].char
                items_rendered += 1
                sprites_to_render -= 1

                if sprites_to_render == 0:
                    # if nothing else to render on this line we fill up the line with "void"
                    number_to_fill_up = self.size["x"] - (todo_line + 1)
                    render_line += self.canvas_owner.void * number_to_fill_up + "\n"
                    items_rendered += number_to_fill_up
                    canvas += render_line
                    
                    break

            number_of_row_to_render -= 1
            if number_of_row_to_render <= 0:
                # prob not here
                number_to_fill_up = self.size["y"] - todo_row - 1
                canvas += line * number_to_fill_up
                break

        return canvas
```